# "Root element not found" - when reading memory stream

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a class that i store in a list.

I serialize it ...

```
        XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        XmlSerializer xm = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<BugWrapper>));

        xm.Serialize(ms, _bugs);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
        string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
        xd.Load(ms);
```

I looked into str and found it to be empty, the collection however has an object.

Any ideas into why this happens?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes - you're saving to the memory stream, leaving it at the *end*. You need to "rewind" it with:

```
ms.Position = 0;
```

just before you create the `StreamReader`:

```
xm.Serialize(ms, _bugs);
ms.Position = 0;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

However, you then need to rewind it *again* before you load into the `XmlDocument` unless you remove those last two lines, which I suspect were just for debugging. Just for good measure, let's close the memory stream as well when we're done with it:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
     XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<BugWrapper>));
     seralizer.Serialize(stream, _bugs);
     stream.Position = 0;

     XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
     doc.Load(stream);
}
```

Comment: Jon you save the day again :) Thank You.